# Matrix with four unknows and three rows (a particular case)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
2&2&1&4.5 \\
4&6&3&12\\
6&9&7&m
\end{array}\right)$$
When I try to solve this, obviously always end up with this $m=x$ term. When you do this wth Gauss, you actually can reach to $y=(459-m)/90$ and $z=(2m-36)/5$, and once you plug $y$ and $z$ in the first equation you get $x=0.75$. Now, when you try to sustitute on the other equations to get $y$ and $z$, always end up with expression like $270=270$ I know it means the system is consistent but  I can´t catch $y$ and $z$.

I also tried to do with cramer and this is what I get:
$\det (M)= 10,  \det(M_{11})= 0.75, \det(M_{12})= 51-2x,  \det(M_{13})=4x-72$
so $x=\det(M_{11})/\det(M)= 0.75, y=(51-2m)/10, z= (2m-46)/2$

What I am missing? This is when I stuck. 
Thank´s for all kind of help.

Comment: No, all the "x´s" terms are positive. G. elimination is about get a a matrix with one´s in the diagonal right and zeros in the rest right? I already tried and is worst because you all in terms of "m"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is spot on with Gauss.

Yes, you always get $x = 0.75$ as fixed.

$y$ and $z$ have a "free" variable that you can set to "any' value you like. For example, choose $m = 0$ and $y = \dfrac{459}{90}$ and $z = -\dfrac{36}{5}$.

Now, when you sub those values in, of course each side should equate.

If you had shown this using Gaussian Elimination, you would have ended up with:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&   0&   0&  0.75\\
      0&   1&  0&  5.1 - 0.2m\\
      0&  0& 1&  0.4m-7.2
    \end{array}\right]$$

It is best to leave the solution showing that you have 'free' variables.

Comment: oh! in the D. LAY book says that!. Thank´s. It is a homework from school and some of my friends reach to m=12.5.....may be they do what youre saying. thank you

Comment: You can certainly choose $m = 12.5$, but recall, you would write the solution in general form showing that you have a 'free' variable that can be anything at all! I showed the simplified GE form. Regards

Comment: Thank´s a lot ! it was trivial . And thank U very much indeed for the simplified form.

Comment: Is when the mark turns green right? sorry i´m new in this but I think this is it.

Comment: Nice to be able to verify good work!